# SwiftUI: NavigationPath always empty

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

The issue I'm facing is that my NavigationPath is always empty. The context is that I have 3 Views.

View A contains the NavigationStack and has two NavigationLinks, to View B and View C respectively. 
View B has a NavigationLink to View C and a toolbar button to View A. 
View C has a NavigationLink to View B and a toolbar button to View A.

```
struct ViewA: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Text("ViewA")
            NavigationLink {
                ViewB(path: $path)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to ViewB")
            }
            NavigationLink {
                ViewC(path: $path)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to ViewC")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ViewB")
            NavigationLink {
                ViewC(path: $path)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to ViewC")
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("ViewA") {
                path = NavigationPath()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewC: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ViewC")
            NavigationLink {
                ViewB(path: $path)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to ViewB")
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("ViewA") {
                path = NavigationPath()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Variable path is always empty.

I've tried multiple implementations, still not working. I'm expecting to have the toolbar button send me to View A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `value` parameter of the `NavigationLink` in conjuction to  the `navigationDestination` modifier for the **path** State variable to be changed, or you could **append** objects that conform to the `Hashable` protocol to navigate (the `navigationDestination` is needed either way).

Here's an example:

```
struct ViewA: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Text("ViewA")
                NavigationLink(value: "B") {
                    Text("Go to B")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(value: "C") {
                    Text("Go to C")
                }
            }
            /// Here you handle possible destinations for the String type
            /// You can define other destinations for different types as well
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { value in
                switch value {
                    case "B": ViewB(path: $path)
                    case "C": ViewC(path: $path)
                    case "D": Text("View \(value)")
                default:
                    Text("View not found")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are `ViewB` and `ViewC`:

```
struct ViewB: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(value: "C") {
                Text("Go to C")
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("ViewA") {
                path = NavigationPath()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewC: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ViewC")
                
            Text("Go To D")
                .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                /// You can also append stuff to the path
                .onTapGesture {
                    path.append("D")
                }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("ViewA") {
                path = NavigationPath()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you append values to the **path** the `navigationDestination` callback for the type appended gets called. It took me a bit to get it when I first saw it but now it is pretty straightforward.
Let me know if you any doubts.

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes more sense now.